# File upload failed MSTeams

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am not able to attach or upload any kind of attachments through my bot integrated with MSTeams .previously it was working fine for me..suddenly it stop working. and I am getting the error as "File upload failed". I also checked my one-drive and cleared all other docs for getting space..but still it is not working.

Comment: Are you uploading the files and sending to bot? Is your bot responding to your messages? Are you able to see attachment option?

Comment: yes , I can see the attachment option and also able to add the attachment , but before clicking on the send button to send the attachment it shows an error saying that 'File upload failed", and bit also not responding.but when I check the oneDrive folder  the file which I tried to upload is there

Comment: And It was working fine for me last week ,suddenly it stopped working.

Comment: We are able to repro the issue and our team is working on it.

Comment: Thank you. Why it is not working ? whats the reason ? Can I resolve that? or Is it an issue from MSTeams side?

Comment: It's an issue with MS Teams Client. We are working on it.